# GA4 - event (conversion) with referer condition

Tags: google-analytics-4

How to setup an event (with conversion) and a referer condition. The referer must NOT be external. Only internal that links to the location must me tracked!

Right now I have 2 events with a `page_location`, but want to add a condition that only allows an internal referer

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps on how to achieve this in GA4

**Assumption**: Let's say your website is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

- Click on the event that you want to add a condition on (from your
  image)
- Go go to the matching conditions section
- Add - `page_referrer`
  --- `matches regular expression (ignore case)` -- `example\.com`

[image]